# Remove non BMP characters from BeautifulSoup object

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner in python. I am using BeautifulSoup to extract data from websites. But whenever the source code of a page contains emoticons, my program stops there. What should I exactly do while/before parsing so that , emoticons/non BMP characters are removed and the page is scraped.

```
import bs4 as bs
import string
import urllib.request

str = 'http://www.storypick.com/harshad-mehta-scam-web-series/' #myurl
source = urllib.request.urlopen(str);
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml');

match=soup.find('div',class_='td-post-content');
str=soup.title.text+"\n";
name=soup.title.text;
for paragraph in match.find_all(['p' , 'h4' , 'h3' , 'h2' , 'blockquote']):
    str+=paragraph.text+"\n";
print(str);
```

Output:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 161-161: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk
```

Comment: Change `bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')` to `bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')` and see what happens. It is hard to give you an exact solution, because you did not share the website you are scraping.

Comment: @antfuentes87 I added the link and tried your approach. Doesn't work.

Comment: Just added my answer, that should do the trick for you.

Comment: @antfuentes87 I tried your solution. It is still not working.  
https://ibb.co/bOYdDS  https://ibb.co/mYiZnn

Answer (score 0):

I switched to using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master) which makes things simpler. This is a simpler example than what you are trying to do, but it does work. You should have no problems finishing your script now.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

requestURL = 'http://www.storypick.com/harshad-mehta-scam-web-series'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36'}

with requests.Session() as session:
    r = session.get(requestURL, headers=headers)
    if r.ok:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
        for paragraph in soup.find_all('p'):
            print (paragraph)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Program Files (x86)/Python36-32/ak/t.py", line 12, in <module>
    print (paragraph)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 378-378: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk

Comment: Hmm, it works perfectly for me? What OS are you running? Is your default language on the OS English? That could have something to do with it? I will try Googling that error and see what I find.

Comment: Did you also try my exact example? Copy and paste?

Comment: https://ibb.co/bOYdDS  https://ibb.co/mYiZnn I did copy & paste. I am running windows 10. Default language is English. Can you share a screenshot of your output please ?

Comment: @antfuentes87, the problem is **not** with `lxml`. Any reason why you changed to `html.parser`? The [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) explicitly say _If you can, I recommend you install and use lxml for speed._ I'm just posting this as I thought new users should be made aware of this fact.

Comment: @Keyur Potdar I don't know what the problem is, I just had him try a few different things. Just odd that my example works fine. And the output is just all the paragraph elements.

Comment: I'm not at all saying anything about your solution. Just the fact that you are suggesting the use of `html.parser` when there is no need. I ran your code with both the parsers, and they are working perfectly fine.

Comment: Yeah, I tried both as well. I changed my answer to use `lxml` (that is what is what I use in my own projects). I just figured he could give it a shot.

Comment: Trying/suggesting the use of other parsers is perfectly fine. But if you suggest a new bs4 user to change the parser from `lxml` to `html.parser`, I thought you should make them aware of the speeds since it is a downgrade.

Comment: Noted for next time. Now we just need to figure out the problem... no idea why it is erroring like that.

Answer (score 0):

Working perfectly for me ! I modified the code a little

```
import bs4 as bs
import string
import urllib

str = 'http://www.storypick.com/harshad-mehta-scam-web-series/' #myurl
source = urllib.urlopen(str);
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source);

match=soup.find('div',class_='td-post-content');
str=soup.title.text+"\n";
name=soup.title.text;
for paragraph in match.find_all(['p' , 'h4' , 'h3' , 'h2' , 'blockquote']):
    str+=paragraph.text+"\n";
print(str);
```